# tornado and django proccesing order

Tags: django, asynchronous, websocket, tornado

We are developing a project using django on tornado.

```
def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
        django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())

    application = Application([(r'/websocket/', planet_socket.WsDate),
                               ('.*', FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
                               ],
                              **settings)

    print options.port
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When we are running the project as above, We take the problems as below.

1. When a request starts(such as showing 10K records to the screen) all other requests are waiting until the first request is completed.
2. Requests which are running on Web Socket are waiting for first request's completion.
3. When a user starts the first request then all other users are waiting the first request's completion.

Sample Project is [here](https://github.com/israfilkara/django_tornado). How Can We fix this problems..

Do you  have any idea ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of WSGIContainer: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer

> Warning
>
> WSGI is a synchronous interface, while Tornado’s concurrency model is
>   based on single-threaded asynchronous execution. This means that
>   running a WSGI app with Tornado’s WSGIContainer is less scalable than
>   running the same app in a multi-threaded WSGI server like gunicorn or
>   uwsgi. Use WSGIContainer only when there are benefits to combining
>   Tornado and WSGI in the same process that outweigh the reduced
>   scalability.

You need to either make your Django app fast enough that you don't mind waiting on it, or run Django and Tornado in two separate processes communicating over the network. Personally I would only run Django in WSGIContainer as part of a transitional strategy to convert everything to Tornado-only; if Django is a part of your long-term strategy then I'd recommend using separate processes.

Comment: we try that seperate processes, but we cannot verify in tornado the user which login in django. so when we seperate this processes how can we authenticate, can you make an example?